# How to Push a New Elixir Release on a Cluster Using exrm?

Tags: elixir, exrm

I do have a simple elixir app running on one node, exrm is doing his job properly by upgrading/downgrading it when needed.

I decided recently to create two nodes (it will be on two separates machines but i want to test it first on localhost)

So i read the following Chris McCord article

https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/01/28/running-elixir-and-phoenix-projects-on-a-cluster-of-nodes

and i have now two nodes,

> n1@127.0.0.1

and

> n2@127.0.0.1

with the following added to mix config

```
config :kernel,
  sync_nodes_optional: [:"n1@127.0.0.1", :"n2@127.0.0.1"],
  sync_nodes_timeout: 10000
```

I was used to do the following

```
mix release
ssh targethost mkdir deploy/releases/x.x.x
scp rel/sequence/releases/x.x.x/appname.tar.gz targethost:deploy/releases/x.x.x
ssh targethost ~/deploy/bin/appname upgrade x.x.x
```

May someone guide me on what to do to deploy upgrade/downgrade both nodes?

Kind regards,

Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Exrm` is a tool for packaging, but what you wanna is a tool for deploying.

You should modified the nodename in `vm.args` during deploying. I use fabfile to do this.

Or maybe you want it: [deploying-elixir-applications-with-edeliver](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/06/deploying-elixir-applications-with-edeliver)